# Unable to base security rule condition on resource data in Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am attempting very simple thing and that is matching `request.auth.uid` to a field value in my *transaction* documents (like this `resource.data.useruid`) in Firebase security rule in order to get transactions of a particular logged in user. However, I don't get any documents while querying for them and get an error instead.

This is how the collection looks like - just one document there with `useruid` field.

[image]

The field's value is mapped to the users *uid* (screenshot taken in the *Authentication -> Users* tab.

[image]

And the rule looks like this

[image]

I should get the one document back but every time I query the documents with that user logged in (I am using angularfire2 for those purposes) I get `Error: Missing or insufficient permissions.`

If I modify the rule condition to return always `true` or if I only check for truthiness of `request.auth.uid` I get the query result alright. The funny thing though is that with `resource.data` involved - eg. checking for value of the `amount` field in the firebase rule - the condition is never met. I tried to write it like

`allow read, write: if resource.data.amount == 3`

and got the error again. Seems like I don't get the `resource.data` Map at all.

I feel like I am missing something obvious, although after reading the guides, it seems alright to me and I am already out of ideas. The debugging capabilities (or lack of) make the whole process very slow.

Could you please explain to me, why I don't get the `resource.data` Map in the firebase security rule or point me to a place where the problem might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have most probably missed one specific point in the doc: your query fails "because it does not include the same constraints as your security rules". See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_authuid

The following, with your security rules works perfectly:

```
firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("xxxx@xxxx.com", "xxxxx")
    .then(function (info) {
        db.collection("transactions").where("userid", "==", info.uid).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
            });
        });

    });
```

If you remove the `where` clause, you get the exact error you are getting

Comment: You are absolutely right, I really missed that one. Your solution works well for me. Thank you!.

Comment: Is there a way to use this rule without querying? I'm accessing the document directly by it's reference and I'm listening to it's updates so I don't want to `get()` it's value. This rule fits perfect to me but it looks like I'm unable to use if I'm going to retrieve only one sigle document by it's id